# Carbon\Carbon giving me issues

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

hello i'm trying to build an application that plots a graph for the last 7 days beginning with today, and i'm using Laravel 5 - Carbon\Carbon date package.. 
so if today is wednesday it would end on tuesday 
if today is friday it would end on thurdsay nxt week

```
    $now = Carbon::now();

    $ar = [];
    for($i=1; $i<7; $i++){
        array_push($ar, $now->subDays($i));
    }

    pr($ar, true);
```

where pr() is a helper function similar to dd() i wrote that just die-dumps in a simple way, but i get this output, with the first problem being that, keeping in mind that today is - Friday, 30th November, 2018,  2018-11-30

```
Array(
[0] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-11-09 12:23:53.793501
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[1] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-11-09 12:23:53.793501
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[2] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-11-09 12:23:53.793501
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[3] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-11-09 12:23:53.793501
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[4] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-11-09 12:23:53.793501
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[5] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-11-09 12:23:53.793501
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )
```

it should continue as 29th, 28th, 27th, but its going far back as 09th of november, and its not even sequencial, like 09, 08, 07, 06, just 09 of november and i dont know what i'm getting wrong, please i need assistance, thanks.

Comment: I believe you have your answer already, but as a side note, you used the loop counter $i to subtract the number of days in the code you posted; in effect, this means you subtracted 1 day from the date object, then 2 days from the same date object the second time around, then 3 days, etc. which is why you ended up with a date 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21 days in the past.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a function on a carbon object, the object will update itself and return a reference to the object. So, your `$ar` array contains several references to the same object. Every time you use `subDays` you are actually updating every object in your array.

If you want to fill your array with different carbon objects, you have to create a new instance every time. For example, like this:

```
$ar = [];
for($i=1; $i<7; $i++){
    array_push($ar, now()->subDays($i));
}
```

[`now()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-now) is a helper function in Laravel that returns a new instance of `Carbon::now()`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the solution to your question so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$day = Carbon::today();

$ar = [];

for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++){
 array_push($ar, $day);
 $day->subDay(1);
}
```

Here `$day->subDay(1);` method is modifying the object value itself subtracting by 1 instead of returning the modified value.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = [];
for($i=1; $i<7; $i++){
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $ar[] = $now->subDays($i);
}
```

Carbon will update it's instance everytime you call subdays, so you need to reninitilize.